# How to check if a jFormattedTextField is empty?

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

I saw some similiar questions about this one, but, none of them seems to be helping me here.

I have a jFormattedTextField with this mask "##-##-####", and i get date to send to a PostgreSQL with dd-MM-yyyy, This field is for birth date.

When I was using normal jTextfield and the user had to input "/" or "-" to separate day, month and year, it was ok to check if it was empty, however, with the mask on, i'm not able to check.

```
else if (jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Por favor completar o campo Data"); //please complete date field

            try {
                conecta.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                conecta.conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pessoa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

And, here it's where the netbeans says the mistake is:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");
        java.util.Date utilDate = null;
                try {
                    utilDate = formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText());
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(Pessoa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        pst.setDate(5, sqlDate);
        pst.executeUpdate(); //executa o SQL
```

this is what a get from netbeans:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Date.getTime()" because "utilDate" is null

Comment: What does logger statement (for the `formatter.parse`) display

Comment: so after `catch (ParseException ex)`  is it OK just to continue?

Comment: I get this

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "  -  -    "

Comment: I would suggest calling `getValue` instead of `getText` ... check to see if it's `null`

Comment: answering about the `catch (PaserException ex)`

Yes, it will be okay to continue, if i can get the null field

Comment: I've just tried with `getValue`

Didn't work

Comment: If you have that exception then the value of `utilDate` is going to be null, so no it is not OK to continue.

Comment: @LuísFelipeAmbrozin You're just not dealing with the situation in which the value is `null` (or the text is invalid and can't be parsed).  You need to decide what to do if the the value is not valid, rather then just trying to convert it to `java.sql.Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JFormattedTextField` should already be configured with a `SimpleDateFormatter` which will be doing the parsing/formatting/validation of the text.

In this case, you should be using `getValue` instead of `getText`

```
java.util.Date utilDate = jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getValue();
if (utilDate != null) {
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    pst.setDate(5, sqlDate);
} else {
    // I don't know what you want to do in this case...
}
pst.executeUpdate(); //executa o SQL
```

Comment: Ok, I tried, it's working perfectly, fits like a glove, but, I need to show a message to the user that he will not get then scared.

Thank you